# How to display data using ngFor from POST request

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and I'm having a hard time to display my data from POST request to table using *ngFor, I tried many approach but have no luck at all.

I tried to use keyvalue pipe but it only loops 4 times (Coz I think it loops by the number of my columns from database which is 4 columns

***lesson.component.ts***

```
public lessons: Lessons[] = [];
  public const lesson_mapped;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.Lesson.showLesson().subscribe((response: Response)=>{
      this.lessons = response;
      this.lesson_mapped = Object.keys(this.lessons).map(key =>({type: key, value: this.lessons[key]}))
      console.log(this.lesson_mapped);
    })
  }
```

***lesson.service.ts***

```
showLesson():Observable<any[]>{
    return this.http.post('http://localhost/mizpah-backend/lesson.php',{responseType: "json"})
  }
```

***lesson.component.html***

```
<tr *ngFor = "let lesson of lesson_mapped | keyvalue">
            <th scope="row">{{ i + 1 }}</th>
            <td>{{ lesson.lesson_title }}</td>
            <td>{{ lesson.date }}</td>
            <td>{{ lesson.remarks }}</td>
            <td style="text-align: center">
              <a class="nav-link">Download</a>
            </td>
</tr>
```

I want it to display in 1 row, these are my columns (lesson_no,lesson_title, lesson_date, remarks). But what happened is the table row loops 4 times.

Comment: The element with the `*ngFor` attribute will be generated for each element of the loop. This `*ngFor` iterates over each property of the object. So this is exactly expected behavior.

Comment: How can I display all the property in one row? I'm new to this I'm sorry.

Comment: Put the NG For on the td.  you have several other mistakes though, it sounds like you really need to learn the basics. I would suggest you look at some tutorials